# Faild to Map data to decodable object Moya Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, api, moya

Hi i want to get a code string from json API to label and i am getting an error as Faild to Map data to decodable object. I debug and get request failure error as here.

> objectMapping(Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Here is my code

```
struct Benefits: Codable {

  var benefitsCode:String?
  enum CodingKeys:String, CodingKey {
    case benefitsCode = "benefitsCode" 
  }

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    benefitsCode = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .benefitsCode) 
  }
}
```

Model Class

```
final class BenefitsModel: EventNode {
  weak var output: BenefitsModelOutput!
  private var benefits: [Benefits] = []
  private var benefitsProvider = DataManager<BenefitsAPI, [Benefits]>()

  override init(parent: EventNode?) {
    super.init(parent: parent)
  } 

  private func load() {
    benefitsProvider.load(target: .benefitsCode, withActivity: true) {[weak self] result in
    switch result {
      case .success(let response):      
        print(response,"here chck")
        self?.benefits = response
        self?.output.perform(action: .didLoad)
      case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
 }
```

Here is the Json from API

```
 { 
    "name": String, "surname": String, "benefitsCode": String, "facebookShareText": String, "twitterShareText": String, "mailShareText": String, "amountOfUses": int 
 }
```

API layer fetch is

```
enum BenefitsAPI {
case benefitsCode 
 }

extension BenefitsAPI: TargetType, AccessTokenAuthorizable {
var path: String {
    switch self {
    case .benefitsCode: return "/api/benefits"      
    }
   }

var method: Moya.Method {
    switch self {
    case .benefitsCode: return .get
   
    }
 }
var task: Task {
    switch self {
    case .benefitsCode: return .requestPlain
    
   
    }
 }

var authorizationType: AuthorizationType? {
    .bearer
        
}
```

}

Comment: The error is pretty clear - the decoder is finding a dictionary in the json where your data structure is indicating an array.  I'd guess that somewhere you are trying to decode an  `[Benefit]`, but as you haven't included this code or the json you are trying to decode we're not going to be able to help much

Comment: Hi @flanker my json response is some thing like this {
  "name": String,
  "surname": String,
  "benefitsCode": String,
  "facebookShareText": String,
  "twitterShareText": String,
  "mailShareText": String,
  "amountOfUses": int
}    i need benefitCode to fetch and print on label

Comment: "Something like" isn't all that helpful, but the example you've given is a dictionary, not an array.   Maybe add the actual JSON received from the API to the question if you're still having problems?

Comment: I updated my question with Json recieved from API please have a look if you can help .

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't supplied the load function that does the loading and decoding it's not possible to provide a full answer as that is the most relevant code.

Also the JSON you have provided is not valid JSON. It looks more like an interface definition than the returned data.  However, for the sake of demonstrating the approach, let's convert it to valid JSON:

```
{
  "name": "String",
  "surname": "String",
  "benefitsCode": "String",
  "facebookShareText": "String",
  "twitterShareText": "String",
  "mailShareText": "String",
  "amountOfUses": "int"
}
```

It's relatively obvious that this represents a single record, not an array of records, but as the record has the key in it you are looking for we'll again continue to demonstrate the approach.  Therefore to get that data out you just need to

```
let jsonData = Data(json.utf8) 
//where json is the String of JSON above

let benefit = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Benfit.self, from: jsonData). 
//real world code should use `do ... try ... catch` not 'try!`

print(benefit) 
// prints: Benefits(benefitsCode: Optional("String"))
```

Comment: Can you please configure now i updated my question with load function and api layer

Comment: I'd never use a 3rd party download library, so not familiar with Moya, but I'd guess you need to configure the data manager to return the data provided by the API, so my guess would be to change it to return a single object rather than an array: `private var benefitsProvider = DataManager<BenefitsAPI, Benefit>`

Comment: Yes i change it      private var benefitsProvider = DataManager<BenefitsAPI, Benefits>()
and its working but how i can get code text on label i call in VC didload  as myLbl.text = code.benefitCode where  code is var code:Benefits? and it is return nil

Comment: If the response has answered your question it's good practice to accept the answer.  Accessing the API is asynchronous, so you need to update the label in the completion handler, not in `viewDidLoad` as when the view loads the data won't have been fetched.

Answer (score 0):

AS @flanker comment i just need to configure the data manager to return the data provided by the API, to change it to return a single object rather than an array. The model is fine to decode.

```
var benefits:Benefits!
private var benefitsProvider = DataManager<BenefitsAPI, Benefits>()
```